# Make top level window transparent for mouse clicks

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, window-managers

I want to be able to redirect mouse clicks to the window below my application. An example: My application is arranged like in the picture below. The red rect is the invisible border of my top level window. No I cant click the close button of the window below. How can I make (only) my top level widget transparent for mouse clicks? (`setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);` does not work)

[image]

Comment: Is your underneath window possibly a child of the invisible top level window?

Comment: No the underneath window is not a child of the invisible top level window.

Comment: What GUI platform are developing on, X Windows? Also, does it *never* work, or only when you try and click the close button?

Comment: Currently just X11, but Win and OSX is planned. It works never.

Comment: Did you try `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground`?

Comment: Yes, this just makes visual transparency. It's used in the picture too.